# Morphia with Abstract Class Annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to understand how to properly annotate a base class and the extending class with Morphia.  Given the following example would I `@Entity` to the Employee class or just the Developer class?

```
public abstract class Employee {
    @Property
    private String firstName;
    @Property
    private String lastName;
    @Property
    private Date startDate;
}


@Entity
public class Developer extends Employee{

    @Embedded
    private List<String> ProjectList;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need the `@Property` annotations
2. If you want to use different collections for the subclasses, this is fine. If you want to use a single collection for all subclasses, you would only need to annotate `Employee`. Since you don't have a schema, both approaches are perfectly fine and it only dependes on how you want to access your data later on.